# Couchbase Lite 2.0.0 C# case insensitive query

Tags: c#, couchbase, sql-like, case-insensitive, couchbase-lite

I'm using Couchbase Lite 2.0.0 in my app and am trying to do a case insensitive string search for terms which contain a given phrase e.g. if the value is `hello, world!` then the phrase `o, w` should return it but `ow` should not.

According to the [couchbase docs](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/couchbase-lite/csharp.html#query) is should be able to achieve this with the `LIKE` operator and wildcard matches:

> Note that since like does a case insensitive match, the following query will return "landmark" type documents with name matching "Royal Engineers Museum", "royal engineers museum", "ROYAL ENGINEERS MUSEUM" and so on.

So my code is;

```
...
.Where(Expression.Property(myPropertyName).Like(Expression.String($"%{phrase}%"));
...
```

This works as expected *EXCEPT* it is still case sensitive.

I've tried using `.Collate(Collation.ASCII().IgnoreCase(true)`

I've also tried using the REGEX operator with `(?i)` mode but this caused a panic.

I'm thinking of using the Full Text Search functionality but this is probably overkill for this simple situation.

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They recently changed it to be case sensitive!

To make it case insensitive they are now advising use of `Function.Lower` like this:

```
...
.Where(Function.Lower(Expression.Property(myPropertyName))
    .Like(Expression.String($"%{phrase?.ToLower()}%"));
...
```

It seems a bit hacky. Hopefully you don't have to [deal with any Turkish i's](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+turkish+i+problem)!

For more info see...

[Couchbase lite 2.0., DB22, like became case sensitive?](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-2-0-db22-like-became-case-sensitive/15842)

[Introducing the Query Interface in Couchbase Mobile 2.0](https://blog.couchbase.com/sql-for-json-query-interface-couchbase-mobile/)

[Case Insensitive `like`](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/case-insensitive-like/16815)

Comment: Perfect, and great resources shared. Thanks!